# Make dataframe into wide format and group multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
example <- data.frame(
  PID = c(11191, 11192, 21191, 21193),
  NS = c(1,5,9,13),
  NR = c(2,6,10,14), 
  SE = c(3,7,11,15), 
  GR = c(4,8,12,16)
)
```

I want to make the dataframe into a wide format such that the last digit of `PID` is the grouping variable. Here is the desired solution:

```
example_solution <- data.frame(
  target = c(1119, 2119),
  NS_1 = c(1,9),
  NR_1 = c(2,10),
  SE_1 = c(3, 11),
  GR_1 = c(4,12),
  NS_2 = c(5,NA),
  NR_2 = c(6, NA),
  SE_2 = c(7, NA),
  GR_2 = c(8, NA),
  NS_3 = c(NA,13),
  NR_3 = c(NA, 14),
  SE_3 = c(NA, 15),
  GR_3 = c(NA, 16)
)
```

How may I achieve this? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
example %>%
  mutate(one = PID %% 10, PID = PID %/% 10) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = PID, names_from = one,
              values_from = -c(PID, one), names_sep = "_")
# # A tibble: 2 × 13
#     PID  NS_1  NS_2  NS_3  NR_1  NR_2  NR_3  SE_1  SE_2  SE_3  GR_1  GR_2  GR_3
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  1119     1     5    NA     2     6    NA     3     7    NA     4     8    NA
# 2  2119     9    NA    13    10    NA    14    11    NA    15    12    NA    16
```

You can change the column order using something from [dplyr: order columns alphabetically in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29873293/3358272), perhaps `%>% select(PID, sort(names(.))`.

Answer (score 3):

A base R solution with `reshape`

```
reshape(
    transform(
        example,
        id = PID %% 10,
        PID = PID %/% 10
    ),
    direction = "wide",
    idvar = "PID",
    timevar = "id",
    sep = "_"
)
```

gives

```
   PID NS_1 NR_1 SE_1 GR_1 NS_2 NR_2 SE_2 GR_2 NS_3 NR_3 SE_3 GR_3
1 1119    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8   NA   NA   NA   NA
3 2119    9   10   11   12   NA   NA   NA   NA   13   14   15   16
```

Comment: I applaud the use of `reshape`, that function can be _confusing_!

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

dcast(as.data.table(example), 
      substr(PID, 1, 4) ~ substr(PID, 5, 5),     # PID %/% 10 ~ PID %% 10
      value.var=c("NS", "NR", "SE", "GR"))

#       PID  NS_1  NS_2  NS_3  NR_1  NR_2  NR_3  SE_1  SE_2  SE_3  GR_1  GR_2  GR_3
#    <char> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
# 1:   1119     1     5    NA     2     6    NA     3     7    NA     4     8    NA
# 2:   2119     9    NA    13    10    NA    14    11    NA    15    12    NA    16
```